# swiftの基本

Tags: swift

基本のラベルとsliderを表示するものを作っているんですが、Xcode上で`label.text`のコードがなぜエラーになるのかわかりません。

**エラー**

```
Swift Compiler Error

Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'text'

Did you mean 'next'? (UIKit.UIResponder)
```

**コード**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var label: UIView!
   @IBAction func showValue(_ sender: UISlider) {
      label.text = "\(sender.value)"
   }
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

}
```

Comment: [ツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)をご覧ください。プログラミングに関する質問は、画像でなく質問中にあなた自身の言葉で説明された方がよいでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージの通りです。`label`は`UIView`型の変数として定義されていて、`UIView`には`text`というプロパティは無いので、存在しないプロパティに値を代入しようとしているため、コンパイラの型チェックでエラーになっています。